# accuracy loss 0.7% after I use .pb model(tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I finetune an albert tiny model(classification mission). after I trained 133841 steps, I do the prediction, the  accuracy of the  classification task is 82.5%. I add an estimator.export_savemodel in my code so I can store the model as .pb format.

Then I used this pb model to for a tensorflow-serving.the client also did a predicition. However, the accuracy fall 0.7%. Could you please help me to find the reason?

below are the my client.py

```
from __future__ import print_function

import grpc
import requests
import tensorflow as tf
import tokenization
import numpy as np
import time


from run_classifier_albert import *

from tensorflow_serving.apis import predict_pb2
from tensorflow_serving.apis import prediction_service_pb2_grpc

from tensorflow.contrib.util import make_tensor_proto

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('server','0.0.0.0:localhost',
                           'PredictionService host:port')

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS
data_dir=""
processor = MyProcessor()
label_list = processor.get_labels()
tokenizer = tokenization.FullTokenizer(
       vocab_file='./vocab.txt', do_lower_case=False)

def main(_):
  examples = processor.get_test_examples(data_dir)
  print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\n", len(examples))
  index =0
  channel = grpc.insecure_channel(FLAGS.server)
  request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
  request.model_spec.name ='Albert'
  request.model_spec.signature_name = 'serving_default'
  stub = prediction_service_pb2_grpc.PredictionServiceStub(channel)

  with open("predict_result_full_convert.txt", 'w', encoding ="utf-8") as f1:
   #request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
   #request.model_spec.name ='Albert'
   #request.model_spec.signature_name = 'serving_default'
   #stub = prediction_service_pb2_grpc.PredictionServiceStub(channel)
   for (ex_index, example) in enumerate(examples):
    feature = convert_single_example(ex_index,example,label_list,128,tokenizer)
    input_ids = feature.input_ids
    new_input_ids = [input_ids]
   # print("the shape of the old input_id is: ", np.shape(input_ids))
   # print("the shape of the new input_id is: ",np.shape(new_input_ids))

    input_mask = feature.input_mask
    label_id = feature.label_id
    segment_ids = feature.segment_ids
   # request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
   # request.model_spec.name = 'Albert'
   # request.model_spec.signature_name = 'serving_default'

    request.inputs["label_ids"].CopyFrom(make_tensor_proto(label_id))
    request.inputs["input_ids"].CopyFrom(make_tensor_proto([input_ids],shape=[1,128]))
    request.inputs["input_mask"].CopyFrom(make_tensor_proto([input_mask],shape=[1,128]))
    request.inputs["segment_ids"].CopyFrom(make_tensor_proto([input_mask],shape=[1,128]))
    startTime = time.time()
    #stub = prediction_service_pb2_grpc.PredictionServiceStub(channel)
    result = stub.Predict(request, 10.0)
    endTime = time.time()
    costime = endTime-startTime


    probabilities = result.outputs['probabilities'].float_val
    #print("the probabilities is: ", probabilities)
    max_score = max(probabilities)
    #print("the max score is: ", max_score)
    value = max_score
    for i in range(len(probabilities)):
      if value == probabilities[i]:
       target_index = i
       #print("target_index is: ", i)    
    predict_label = label_list[target_index]

    if ex_index % 10000 == 0:
      print("##################################\n", ex_index)
    f1.write(str(predict_label) + '\t' + str(max_score) + '\t' +str(costime))
    f1.write('\n')
    #if ex_index == 1000:
       # break
  f1.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.run()
```

Comment: Which version of Tensorflow are you using? Also, make sure that you are replicating all the Data-Preprocessing steps as in the Saved Model. You can try saving the Model using `model.save` or `tf.keras.models.save` and see how it goes.